# Создать из коллекции две разные коллекции

Tags: c#, .net, linq

У меня есть коллекция с полями `Name`, `Total` и ещё одной коллекцией.

```
IEnumerable<DetailSection> detailedViewResultSection,

public class DetailSection
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<DetailItem> Items { get; set; }
    public decimal Total { get; set; }
}
```

Я хочу эту коллекцию разделить на две, например: если у тебя "имя1" или "имя2" то записать в новую коллекцию, иначе записать в другую.

```
IEnumerable<DetailSection> list = new List<DetailSection>();
foreach (var c in detailedViewResultSection)
{
    //if
    foreach (var b in c.Name.Where(x => x.Equals(Corporate) || x.Equals(Group))) // private const string Corporate = "Corporate";
    {
        list = detailedViewResultSection;
    }
    //else
    foreach (var b in c.Name.Where(x => !x.Equals(Corporate) || !x.Equals(Group)))
    {
        list = detailedViewResultSection;
    }
}
```

Смысл условия в том что: если `Name` равно `Corporate` или `Group`, то создать новую коллекцию только с этими именами и соответственно их данными.

Сейчас условия не работают и возвращает две коллекции со всеми значениями

Могли бы вы подсказать что я делаю неверно и как правильно разделить такую коллекцию?

Comment: А с какой целью вы это делаете?

Comment: Необходимо построить разные таблицы в excel для двух разных типов

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Достаточно простые Linq запросы подойдут?

```cs
IEnumerable<DetailSection> list1 = detailedViewResultSection.Where(x => x.Name == Corporate || x.Name == Group);
IEnumerable<DetailSection> list2 = detailedViewResultSection.Where(x => x.Name != Corporate && x.Name != Group);
```

Comment: Да, это даже лучше 
Что-то я замудрил 
Спасибо большое!